# Commandline tool to change RGB value of GeoTIFF

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, color, rgb

I would like to change the rgb-value of raster-tiffs from 0,0,0 to 1,1,1.
Is there a commandline-tool that can change the rgb-values of GeoTIFF files?

At the moment I use irfanview to change the color. As long as I keep the TFW-file of the GeoTIFF but do change the color for many raster files is not very conveinient.

Comment: Use https://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Orfeo Toolbox, a c++ library with a lot of usefull applications. In your case, otbcli_BandMathX would do the job in one line:

> otbcli_BandMathX -il input.tif -out output.tif -exp "((im1b1==0) and
>   (im1b2==0)and (im1b3==0))?{1,1,1}:im1"

That is: if the three bands of your raster are equal to zero, then write a pixel of value [1,1,1] otherwise write the value of the first image. More info about this tool [here](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/recipes/bandmathx.html). It is worth noting that you can use gdal properties for writing the image based on what they call extended file names, e.g. `-out "output.tif?&gdal:co:COMPRESS=LZW&gdal:co:TILED=YES"`

Answer (score 1):

`gdal_calc.py` will work, but it needs a few steps as it will only output a single band:

```
# Extract the bands with gdal_calc and edit the value of each band
gdal_calc.py -A in.tif -A_band=1 -B in.tif -B_band=2 -C in.tif -C_band=3 --calc  "A+((A*B*C)==0)" --outfile=outA.tif
gdal_calc.py -A in.tif -A_band=1 -B in.tif -B_band=2 -C in.tif -C_band=3 --calc  "B+((A*B*C)==0)" --outfile=outB.tif
gdal_calc.py -A in.tif -A_band=1 -B in.tif -B_band=2 -C in.tif -C_band=3 --calc  "C+((A*B*C)==0)" --outfile=outC.tif

# merge the out files
gdal_merge.py -separate -o out.tif outA.tif outB.tif outC.tif
```

This is not very performant, so if anyone has a better idea ... Maybe an own python solution would work better.